# Why isn't my end = "" function working when being run?

Tags: python

When I ran this code in Python, it said that a syntax error had occurred at the equal sign.

```
x = int(input('Enter a number greater than 0:'))
while x <= 0:
    x = int(input('Enter a number greater than 0:'))
for i in range (x):
    print ("x", end="")
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I don't think this works in python 2

Comment: "end=..." is part of the print function in Python 3, so it won't work in Python 2 @RSon1234

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-UQbOhEG8nqc/WdGzEwLmVoI/AAAAAAAAA-E/EXFfOr7mP0IaiMkK1dQTUtOqMJKLRddnQCL0BGAYYCw/h1224/2017-10-01.jpg

Comment: Based on your image you are using python 2.7.  it won't work

Comment: I am using Python 2

Comment: Thats why it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things wrong with it

**1. Using the print function in Python 2**

You cannot use the syntax "print('something', end='')" in Python 2. The print statement in Python 2 has no attribute "end". It should just be print(x) or print x.

**2. Trying to print the variable x in the loop**

I think here you want it to print something like this:

```
x = 3
for i in range(x):
    print(i)

1 2 3
```

But you put this instead:

```
x = 3
for i in range(x):
    print(x)

3 3 3
```

Also, you put it as a string instead of the variable, so you won't even get that:

```
x = 3
for i in range(x):
    print('x')

x x x
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already correctly pointed out, you are using `python2`, and so print is still a `statement` and not a `method`, and it is written like :

```
print "your text"
```

Hence you not being able to access the `end=` method.

---

Now for some work abouts for them (`python2`):

1. The easiest, `import` the python3 print method.

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in xrange(x):
    print(x, end="")
```

2. Otherwise `store` the values that you want to print in a string and then print it at last.

```
s=''
for i in xrange(x):
    s+=str(i)

print(s)
```

3. Using `list comprehension` and `join`

```
print ''.join(str(i) for i in xrange(x))
```

For both, `#driver values` :

```
In : x = 3
Out : 012
```

---

**Edit :** in case it was as you wrote, and you want to print `x` `x` number of times, an easier way to do that is to do :

```
print str(x) * x

Out : 333
```